# I'd like to know why I'm getting this error when using pip install pystan==2.19.1.1 command line

Tags: pip, pystan

I'm using this command line to install facebook prophet that I'll gonna use for my capstone project in stock price prediction.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX8nd.png)

Comment: Update: I already managed to install prophet in anaconda command prompt using the following command lines:

`conda install -c conda-forge prophet`
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken prophet`
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/prophet_dev prophet`

Now the problem that I have is [this](https://imgur.com/a/q2dshlt)

Answer (score 1):

How to install modules using command window:

1st- (In a python terminal) Run This:

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable)+'\Scripts\\')
```

2nd- Copy returned path into file explorer

3rd- Click in file window again (highlighting text) and simply type "cmd" and hit enter

That should open the command prompt window IN THE RIGHT PATH

Now, (in the command prompt window) type:

> pip install (and whatever you want installed)